# How is the Actionscript 3.0 sample Maze game's code included?

Tags: actionscript-3, import, include

I can't find the line in the Adobe samples for a maze game where the actual .as code is included into the project. This is fundamental, since my own implementation is just using include "file name";, which isn't working. I also can't use import, since I then can't access the elements placed on the stage. Help, please? The files are available here http://download.macromedia.com/pub/developer/flash_as3_sample_game_1.zip

I tried to debug the code, but I can't even find the point where the constructor is called. The execution starts at "stop()" in frame 1 and then if you step into it, calls the enter frame event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess [Document Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WS3e7c64e37a1d85e1e229110db38dec34-7fa4a.html#WS026C9121-F7D4-496d-94C8-368BF6938149a) is the thing you are looking for.
It is an entry point, the class which is instantiated once Flash Player loaded your SWF.